# webpack 4 sass-loader not generating scss source maps

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, sass-loader

**Problem Summary**

I'm trying to create source maps for my scss files. Webpack runs and compiles scss and js fine in the setup below, but the generated js/css files lack any source maps at all no matter what I try. I've searched around for two days looking for an answer, but my config code seems solid enough. Any idea why scss source maps wouldn't be generated at all? I need them to pickup the scss partials as well.

All the `sourceMap: true` options I've added don't seem to do anything. `devtool: 'source-map'` is the same, no difference. I've tried adjusting the scss entry config to import all .scss files not just the *-main.scss files, but I was met with the same result, nothing.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const entry = require('webpack-glob-entry');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const MinifyPlugin = require("babel-minify-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: entry('./Pages/Themes/**/Javascript/*.js', './Pages/Themes/**/Scss/*-main.scss'),
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/bundles/js/'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    watch: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: [
                                require('autoprefixer'),
                                require('cssnano')
                            ],
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MinifyPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '../css/[name].css',
            sourceMap: true
        })
    ]
};
```

**The code above outputs like so:**

- **bundles**

  - css

    - *theme-main.css*
  - js

    - *theme-main.bundle.js*

Comment: Did you find what the problem was at the end? I have almost the same config as you do and I struggle making it work..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it with the following configuration.

```
devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sa|c|sc)ss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I hope it helps you
Regards.